# Make a div bigger and wider while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

How do I enlarge a `div` while scrolling from a size of 20% width and height in the center to 100% width and height?

I'm currently trying at my first website and I'm almost there. All that is missing is animations and improvements in CSS. One of my ideas is that you have a `div` with a background inside and while scrolling the picture gets bigger up to the whole viewpoint. I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Congratulations on your first website. Good luck on your coding journey.

You can do it by using CSS & JavaScript. There is many way, but I'm writing one here. I hope it will be some good.

Let us call the div with an CSS ID *animatedDiv*.

```
<div id="animatedDiv"></div>
```

**Now, lets style it with CSS**

```
#animatedDiv
{
    margin-top: 200px;
    background: #dc143c;
    min-height: 350px;
    min-width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here, I gave the div a background color, Absolute type of position, and margin-top of 200px. You can change it according to your needs. I used *min-height* and *min-width* property because these value will not be any fixed value, they will change on scroll.

**Now, lets write some JavaScript**

```
var aDiv = document.getElementById("animatedDiv");

function changeWidth() 
{
    var scrollVal = window.pageYOffset;
    var scrollSlow  = (scrollVal / 4);
    
    //Changing CSS Width
    aDiv.style.width = Math.min(Math.max(scrollSlow, 20), 100) + "%";
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() 
{
    requestAnimationFrame(changeWidth);
}, false);
```

Here, on a user define function, I catch the div with it's ID and assign into **aDiv** variable. Then I catch the page offset on Y axis (How much pixel the page was scrolled) and store it into a variable **scrollVal**, Next I divide the value by four (you can use 5, 10 20). It will slow the changing effect.

I've use *Math methods (min and max)* to assign a value between 20 to 100%.

To make the function work on scroll, *window.addEventListener* is used, and the *window.requestAnimationFrame()* method will tell the browser that we wish to perform it as an animation.

I hope it will be some help to you. I don't know did I explain well the process to you or not. English is not my mother language, so please don't mind if I made any grammatically mistake.

Wish you all the best.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. You explained it to me well. My mother language is also not English so don't mind. Thanks

Comment: But something doesn't work in the code. Unfortunately, since I don't have a good knowledge of JS, I can't analyze it. but it could also be that I'm doing something wrong ...

Comment: There's no JQuery in that bit of code though.

Comment: Thanks @Shikkediel for pointing that out, I've updated the answer.
Actually I tried some method before posting this answer, so I used jQuery. Thanks again for correcting the mistake.

Comment: Perhaps you could improve the answer also by adding a demo, preferably an embedded one...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transform` [scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale()) to do it.

`CSS` part will set the element to take 100% of width and height (i use [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#lengths) units), and set it position to fixed (so you will see what happen when you scroll).
Since we gonna change it's scale while scroll, set it initial scale to be 20% of it's original size.

`JS` part will listen to [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll) and scale the div that it won't be less then 20% but also won't be larger then 100%.

Play with the numbers on the condition to get what you need:

```js
const demoDiv = document.querySelector("#demo");
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (pageYOffset*0.0001 > 1 || pageYOffset*0.0001 < 0.2) { return; }
  else { demo.setAttribute('style', 'transform: scale('+pageYOffset*0.0001+');'); }
});
```

```css
body {height: 40000px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
p {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; font-size: 40px;}
#demo {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10vw;
  position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black; 
  color: white;
  transform: scale(0.2); /* since you ask for 20% */     
}
```

```html
<p style="">Scroll to see it grow.</p>  
<div id="demo">My minumum width and height are 20% and i will stop grow when i get to 100%</div>
```