# Make a div smaller when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, scaling

Hi i tried to make the div smaller wqhen scrolling. however i found some article that the div is small then when scroll it make bigger. i wanted the opposite. when run the image is 100% then when scroll it will be smaller. can someone help me please? i am new to this

This is the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-lewin-to1o2b?file=/index.html

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="animatedDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
<style>
  #animatedDiv {
    background: #dc143c;
    min-height: 9000px;
    min-width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>

<script>
  var aDiv = document.getElementById("animatedDiv");

  function changeWidth() {
    var scrollVal = window.pageYOffset;
    var scrollSlow = scrollVal / 4;

    //Changing CSS Width
    aDiv.style.width = Math.min(Math.max(scrollSlow, 20), 100) + "%";
  }

  window.addEventListener(
    "scroll",
    function () {
      requestAnimationFrame(changeWidth);
    },
    false
  );
</script>
```

Comment: ther is no function requestAnimationFrame, but you are calling it

Comment: Change function name `changeWidth` with `requestAnimationFrame`

Comment: but my changeWidth is the inside the requestAnimationFrame

Comment: i found the article here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68732160/make-a-div-bigger-and-wider-while-scrolling

the scrolling is working it just i wanted the other way around

Comment: here `requestAnimationFrame(changeWidth)` your `changeWidth` is parameter not a function name

Comment: if i replace the changeWidth name to requestAnimationFrame , im getting error

Comment: Ah no sorry it's a built in function that calls function, sorry I didn't knew it, you were right

Comment: okieee, no worries

Comment: yes bro it works but right now , the image is small right, when scroll it become bigger.

i want something like when page loaded, the image is full  100% then when scroll it will be smaller rather than bigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with my math logic

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="animatedDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
<style>
  #animatedDiv {
    background: #dc143c;
    min-height: 9000px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>

<script>
  var aDiv = document.getElementById("animatedDiv");

  function changeWidth() {
    var scrollVal = window.pageYOffset;

    //Changing CSS Width

/* This lags if you scroll fast.. aDiv.style.width = (100 - (scrollVal*100/800)) + "%"; 
  I just tried it out, so instead use the code down above, 800 to 1500 doesn't matter, I just increased time of animation
*/
//NOTE this line checks if PERCENT <= 10 then sets width to 10%
  ( (100 - (scrollVal*100/1500)) ) <= 10 ? aDiv.style.width = "10%" : aDiv.style.width = (100 - (scrollVal*100/1500)) + "%";
  }

  window.addEventListener(
    "scroll",
    function () {
      requestAnimationFrame(changeWidth);
    },
    false
  );
</script>
```

Comment: woahhh. Thank you brooo, thank you really, im been thinking about this but no luck.
Thank you very much for your help broooo

Comment: Do you want exlanation? But wait I did it wrong way, I need to change it

Comment: yes pleaseeee. how did u been able do thattt

Comment: Now I edited it take a look at this `aDiv.style.width = (100 - (scrollVal*100/800)) + "%"`  What are we doing is, we are counting how many percent is Yoffset(scrollVal) for 800s,  let me explain for ex. if scrollVal=200 then in 800, it will be 20%, then when scrollVal gets bigger percent will also get bigger for ex. scrollVal 400 percent gets 50% as it's the half of 800, but as we needed to make it decrease, we did this 100-(PERCENT OF scrollVal in 800),  so when percent grows look we get width: (100-20)%  then width: (100-50)%

Comment: ohhh now i understand it . woahh thanks  alot for explaining to me broo. really really thanks a lottt